# How to validate on an absolute date?

Tags: 2010, date-time, validation

I have a datetime field named "Date", and would like to only allow values within a specific range, say March 2015 - June 2016. Is there an easy way to do this? This rather hard one doesn't trigger any message:

```
=AND(AND(YEAR(Date) >= 2015, MONTH(Date) >= 3), AND(YEAR(Date) <= 2016, MONTH(Date) <= 6))
```

The ULS mentioned three truncated General High lines about a custom `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager.RunItemEventReceiver` with correlation id `01333cb4-aeb6-46f5-905f-33aa78511e3a` which i've investigated using this PowerShell script:

```
get-splogevent | ?{$_.Correlation -eq "01333cb4-aeb6-46f5-905f-33aa78511e3a"} | select Area, Category, Level, EventID, Message |Format-List > report.log
```

...which only showed the most severe problem was Monitorable `An SPRequest object was not disposed before the end of this thread.`

What can cause a list validation to be bypassed?

Comment: Really odd, I've literally pasted your code in Date column and I get the validation failed message. Did you check ULS for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
=AND(Date >= DATE(2015, 3, 1), Date <= DATE(2016, 6, 1))
```

I don't know what went wrong before. We probably were confused about False triggering the error message.